# Confusion about the definition of regular maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves

So I'm reading Milne's book on elliptic curves, which is freely available [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext6.pdf).

On page 38, he defines a regular map: Let $k$ be a perfect field. A **regular map** $\varphi : C_{g_1} \to C_{g_2}$ of affine plane curves is a pair of regular functions $(f_1, f_2)$ sending $C_{g_1}(K)$ into $C_{g_2}(K)$ for all fields $K$ containing $k$, i.e. such that for all $K \supset k$,
$$ P \in C_{g_1}(K) \implies (f_1(P), f_2(P)) \in C_{g_2}(K) $$

The regular functions on affine plane curves has been defined on page 29, which he denotes by $k[x,y]$. I don't know if his notation is standard, but he writes $k[X,Y]$ for polynomials in two variables $X$ and $Y$, and the small letters $x$ and $y$ are like 'coordinate functions', and thus $k[x,y]$ are polynomial functions on the curve.

To elaborate a bit more, from what I understand, we can view $k[x,y]$ in two ways: 1. Can view it as polynomial functions (with coefficients in $k$) on the affine plane which we denoted as $k[X, Y]$, but restricted to the curve $C_{g_1}$, and the other way is 2. View it as the quotient $k[X,Y] / (g_1(X, Y))$. This is why the small letters $x$ and $y$ are used i think (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So back to the definition of regular maps, I assume that $f_1, f_2 \in k[x,y]$. **Now, my confusion is on last equation and statement, the part about** 'for all fields $K \supset k$....'. Isn't this always going to be true? Because if $f_1 \in k[x,y]$, and if $P = (a,b) \in K \times K$, then $f_1(P)$ will certainly be in $K$ right? And same for $f_2$. So unless I'm missing something here, I don't see why we must specify the part about 'for all fields $K$..'

Comment: The issue isn't whether $(f_1(P), f_2(P))$ is in $K^2$, it's whether it's in $C_{g_2}(K)$.

Comment: In that case, would it suffice to just say the pair $(f_1, f_2)$ maps $C_{g_1} (\overline{k})$ into $C_{g_2}(\overline{k})$ where $\overline{k}$ is some algebraic closure?

Comment: Once you've shown that regular functions are polynomials with coefficients in $k$, that suffices. I don't know the details of how Milne's set everything up but with the right version of Milne's definition that should be a consequence of the definition, not something that needs to be built in ahead of time.

Comment: In Milne's book, it is defined that if $C_f$ is a curve defined by $f(X, Y) = 0$ for some (irreducible) $f(X,Y) \in k[X,Y]$, then the regular functions on $C_f$ are defined to be the polynomials with coefficients in $k$. You seem to be implying there is some other definition of regular functions, which must then be shown to have coefficients in $k$, could you elaborate a bit more?